# What would be better to add Unit test to: Manager, controller, DAL?

Tags: unit-testing

we have an architecture with 
Controller, Manager (for BL) and a Data Access Layer

Where would it be better to add our Unit Testing. Something tells me that the manager is the best place, because logic will be stored there.

Another idea is that if we test the controller it's more complete (but it sounds too wide in some cases a lot of functionallity would be tested )

And the DAL sounds like THE most atomic part to test, but we are not testing the real outcome.
 BR

MG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely aim to cover the logic inside the manager, while unit testing the controller can certainly yield benefits, too. Don't think that by testing the controller you're also testing what's underneath it - that's why it's called a **unit** test (and not a system/integration one, where you'd call your api from outside and assert against it's responses or DB). So you'll just stub (or mock) the manager during this test, just like you'll do with the DAL while testing the manager.

Testing the actual DAL is certainly a lot trickier (depending on what you're using, ORM & such), and might not be worth looking into.